# Why does this PHP regex not match for accented characters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a quick PHP page, and I need to ignore any Strings with accented characters. I am using this preg_match() string on each word:

"[ÀÁÅÃÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]"

(Quite a brute force method I know, but apparently [a-zA-Z] can match for accented characters)

But the function never seems to return true when it searches Strings with accented characters (Examples: "cheapâ€¦", "gustarÃ­a"...)

I haven't used Regex before, so please point out any stupid mistakes I'm making here!

Comment: Do you know how your strings are encoded (UTF8, for example)? This will be important if you're doing any operations on them, including regular-expression searches.

Comment: You have an encoding problem. Me gustaría haber leído los carácteres normales y bien entrados, pues que de otro modo no tengo ningún idea de lo que estás diciendo. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP regexes need [delimiters](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), like so:

```
preg_match('/[ÀÁÅÃÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]/', "gustarÃ­a");
```

Note that it's also preferable to use single quotes for regex because the dollar sign could be mistaken by php as a variable.

Comment: Fixed the problem perfectly, thankyou, I was not aware of delimiters! +1 to you